# Completeness of the future null infinity in defining a black hole

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, einstein-theory

I am using [these lectures](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0354v1) by Rodnianksi and Dafermos as the reference for this question.

In third point in the list on the top of page 19 they emphasize the importance of completeness of the future null infinity in being able to define a black hole through a
Penrose diagram. I guess by completeness they mean geodesic completeness.

- What is the issue that is being hinted at?

In the statement just below the second diagram on page 21 they seem to be able to read off that the part of the future null infinity that is intersected by the maximal Cauchy development of their chosen Cauchy surface is incomplete.

- I could not understand how this is obvious.

This observation is what they are using to motivate Christodoulou's thinking
of incompleteness of future null infinity as a defining criteria of naked
singularity.

- How does this relate to the other viewpoint of Christodoulou that naked
  singularity is characterized by the non-compactness of the intersection of the
  past of the future null infinity with the Cauchy surface? ([This paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0264-9381/16/12A/302/pdf/0264-9381_16_12A_302.pdf) for reference)

Comment: Where is Willie Wong when you need him?

Comment: Off on vacation. :) There is something strange about your third question: I don't think you are reading Christodoulou right. Take Minkowski space. The past of future null infinity is the whole space, so its intersection with any Cauchy surface is non-compact. In fact what you wrote has more to do with asymptotic flatness and less with naked singularity...

Comment: @Willie Great to see you back from vacation! :) In my third question I was comparing the statements made just below the 2nd diagram on page 21 of the Dafermos-Rodnianski review and the italicized statement at the end of page 13 on Christodoulou's review. Both seem to be trying to characterize the weak censorship conjecture but the arguments are not obviously equivalent to me. Hence seeking help. 

Comment: Dear Scholars,
I have a question as follows :
Let M be an asymptotically flat globally hyperbolic spacetime, and let M* denotes its conformal completion. Consider the set A which is the intersection of future null infinity and closure of causal future of a large sphere S, closure being taken with respect to M*.( assume that intersection is non-empty).
By definition, we usually assume that future null infinity is closed and connected. Is it possible that under some condition(s), this set A is open also ?

Comment: I think it would be best if you created a separate question with what you wrote above. (Click on the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page.)

Answer (score 6):

It will be helpful if you look up the definition of a singularity in spacetime in a standard textbook on GR, Hawking/Ellis "The Large Scale Structure of Spacetime" comes to mind.

About your first question:
The important point is that the definition of a singularity is non-trivial, it cannot simply be defined as a point on a Lorentzian manifold where some tensor diverges (despite the name "singularity", the reason for this is explained in most GR textbooks, the Hawking/Ellis book contains a particularly lucid discussion of the involved ideas). Instead, the defining property is that in the presence of a singularity, there are observers aka reference frames that do not live as long as the universe exists, they either end before the universe itself comes to an end (these are the ones who fall into the singularity) or did not exist when the universe was created (these are the ones escaping from the singularity).

The basic idea is therefore to define a spacetime without singularities to be a spacetime that is geodesically complete. Given a spacetime with a singularity, we can remove all geodesics from the spacetime that end up in the singularity and the ones that emerge from the singularity, and get a spacetime without singularities. The minimum region that we have to remove is then defined as the region comprising the singularity. Therefore the "black hole region" or "singularity" of a spacetime is *defined* to be the minimum subset one has to remove to get a "complete" spacetime in the sense that there are no geodesics that end or begin life prematurely.

Page 19 of your reference is a first step in making these ideas a little bit more precise, it is not a mathematical definition, but a heuristic motivation.

Penrose diagrams are a tool in this context, but not a necessary tool.

I don't understand your second question, page 21 seems to be an explanation of the above ideas using generic Penrose diagrams, this is simply a graphical explanation of what the authors have done before, the diagrams are supposed to show a spacetime with a singularity.

As for your third question, I cannot access the Christodoulou paper.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the motivations for defining the singularity through geodesic completeness as you explained. But in the lectures above they seem to emphasize the need to have the future null infinity geodesically complete, which is a different thing altogether. Thats the point I am not clear about. 



Comment: @Tim The point in page 21 that I can't see is how they are able to read off automatically from the diagram that the part of the future null infinity intersected by the Cauchy development of their chosen Cauchy surface is geodesically *incomplete* (in contrast to what they wanted to be satisfied for defining a black hole) Is there something trivial that I am missing here? 


Comment: @Tim Can you point me to the exact reference in the Hawking and Ellis book that you are referring to? 

Comment: Hi Anirbit, I was not thinking of any specific page of Hawking/Ellis, but about the discussion "how to define a singularity", which is in chapter 5. Maybe it would be helpful if you explain how the definition of your reference is different from the definition in Hawking/Ellis (I don't see an important difference).  Dafermos/Rodnianski don't say that the future null infinity has to be geodesically complete on p.19. Actually they don't define what they mean with "complete" on the page, but mention one possibily: When the past is the complete spacetime (that is when there is no singularity). 

Comment: To your second remark: It is not the future null infinity that is supposed to be geodesically complete, the very notion of this statement does not make any sense. The intersection of the Cauchy surface and future null infinity is empty in the first diagram on page 21, as it should be, the Cauchy surface exists in finite time, for a properly chosen reference frame. 

Comment: continued...The diagram illustrates that there is a Cauchy surface (a non-trivial fact for general spacetimes), that it is in the past of future null infinity and therefore the past of future null infinity comprises the whole spacetime (no singularity).

Comment: Correction of my last remark: The first picture on page 21 shows a Cauchy surface such that its future and past does not comprise the whole spacetime, instead there are both geodesics that end before and geodesics that start after the Cauchy surface (lighter gray), therefore there is a singularity.

Comment: @Tim Thanks a lot for your help. You say that "It is not the future null infinity that is supposed to be geodesically complete", then what am I supposed to read of the 3rd point made in the list at the top of page 19? My entire question is about that point. What does that imply? Just below the second diagram on page 21 they say "where we are to understand also in the above that I+ is incomplete.." How is this obvious? 

Comment: Sorry, a simple misunderstanding: Let's say that $I^+$ is complete if the whole manifold M is geodesically complete, like the authors do.
When there is no singularity, M is geodesically complete and every point in M lies on a geodesic starting in $I^-$ and ending in $I^+$,
like in the Penrose diagram of the Minkowski spacetime at the bottom of page 17...


Comment: ...in the Penrose diagram of page 21 there are geodesics starting in $I^-$ that do not end in $I^+$, and vice versa geodesics that end in $I^+$ but do not start in $I^-$, therefore there is a singularity and
$I^+$ is not complete by definition. It's really as simple as that.

Comment: The second diagram pictures the formation of a singularity along the geodesic on the left, where the label $\tau$ is and the little circle. This geodesic ends in the singularity and does not reach $I^+$, therefore $I^+$ is incomplete. Hope that helps...

Comment: The dashed lines are itself not part of the spacetime.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for your answer. I have also found some references for this notion of complete future null infinity that I have posted as an answer. I can't see any diagram on page 21 of the Dafermos-Rodnianski lectures where there is any "geodesic on the left" or "the label $\tau$". What are you referring to? 


Comment: @TimvanBeek Not to dredge up ancient history, but I take issue with your claim that "given a spacetime with a singularity, we can remove ... and get a spacetime without a singularity". It is a standard result that any strictly smaller open submanifold of a connected pseudo-Riemannian manifold must be geodesically incomplete-- this can be demonstrated by considering a normal neighborhood of any point on the boundary. If your notion of singular behavior is geodesic incompleteness, then, there is no hope of extracting a nonsingular open submanifold of a singular spacetime.

Answer (score 0):

At least about the definition of "complete future null infinity" I found some answers on the 8th page of [these lectures](http://www.math.princeton.edu/~seri/homepage/papers/BE2008.pdf) by Klainerman.

I would be glad to hear of some explanations about how the two definitions given on that page relate to each other and how are they related to the notion explained by Tim in the comments to his answer. (Tim is calling the future null infinity to be complete if the whole manifold is geodesically complete)

Also these seem closely related to the idea of calling a hypersurface as being "generated by complete null geodesics". I would like to know what this means and why this is often used as a condition for the event horizon to satisfy.

Comment: Future null infinity is not "physically present" in the space-time:  it is a formal boundary and you cannot really consider it a null hypersurface of your Lorentzian manifold. In the case of strongly asymptotically flat space-times, you can conformally compactify and take a portion of the conformal boundary to be future null infinity, and you can then look at its completeness. The second definition given by Klainerman in that survey article applies to a larger class of space-times. When your space-time is sufficiently nice that both can be applied, the definitions agree.

Comment: The first definition on pg 8 of your linked article is essentially the definition of "generated by future-complete null geodesics". If you switch time orientation you get the definition for past-complete null geodesics. In general it is hard for a hypersurface to be generated by both future and past complete null geodesics, as it often will imply a null-splitting theorem http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9909158 (and so the space-time will be geometrically special). 

Comment: @Willie Thanks! So you are saying that a hypersurface being "generated by future complete null geodesics" is the same as it being "geodesically complete with respect to future directed null geodesics". (I wonder then why these two different terminologies exist!) So can you shed light on why a demand is made for the event horizon to be "generated by complete null geodesics" ? Does it follow from say the 3 conditions and definition of a black hole as given on the top of page 19 of the Dafermos-Rodnianski lecture? 

Comment: @Willie Thought of adding that I have often seen lines of argument based on the fact that the boundary of causal/chronal future/past of a point is "generated by future/past directed null geodesics". In globally hyperbolic spaces an extension of this that I see getting used often is that the boundary of the chronal future/past of compact orientable spacelike submanifolds are also "generated by null geodesics" orthogonal to them (and some more about not containing any conjugate points) 

Comment: @Willie I wonder how much of the above holds if one replaces points by compact or closed in the general case and just closed sets in the globally hyperbolic case. At least in the black hole area theorem of Hawking one seems to using the generation by conjugate point free null geodesic property for boundaries of causal future of closed sets though the initial theorem seemed to be proven only for some special kind of compact sets. The black hole area theorem hinges on the future directed null geodesic completeness of the event horizon. 